# Reopening the question about dynamic image generation?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question, reopen-request

I came across this question when it was at 3/5 close votes for being unclear :

[How are dynamic images programmed?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/316818/1130)

I didn't think it was unclear at the time, however I could see how people unfamiliar with this kind of concept might not understand it, so edited it to clarify the question.

It got closed anyways, and now I am looking to get it reopened.

This kind of image manipulation is happening a lot more online, and is especially common in shopping websites, even [Amazon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ay7q.jpg). As online shopping becomes more popular, this kind of question will keep coming up with new programmers, so it doesn't make sense to me that we would close it here.

The question is not unclear, and is even a slightly more advanced version of dynamic image generator. Typically there is only a hue/color shift involved with a basic stock photo, but the question is specifically asking about a site that uses a combination of images, each with their own hue/color shift applied.

It's not unclear, and I don't think it's off-topic, too broad, primarily opinion based, or any of the other close reasons.

So can we get it reopened?

Comment: I believe Amazon actually has a public, or semi-public API for this sort of thing.

Comment: I cast the final close vote, because I had a difficult time understanding what it was the asker was trying to learn. Rereading it, it is asking for a primer on the topic that is likely too broad. However, you were able to answer it in a reasonable amount of space, so I voted to reopen and reversed my downvote.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of at least 3 variations on how to process these types of images (i.e., image stacking, image replacement, on the fly image masking, etc.).

We can only guess at how this was implemented.

The question is well worded, with a great example site. That doesn't stop it from being too broad.  Just explaining the method you did (image stacking, although there may be a better name for it), your answer is fairly long. **It is a good answer**. There are some very detailed aspects that you could have delved into further.

Comment: I would be interested in hearing the other methods, this kind of thing is interesting to me. I was hoping it would get other answers. I definitely don't think it's too broad though, as the scope of the question is very narrow. Perhaps if it was asking for a detailed description of the code I could see it being too broad, but I suppose by that definition half of stack overflow is too-broad too. The concept is a narrow topic with a limited number of solutions, all which are relatively similar. I'm hoping to get the reopen votes with a meta question, but I suppose if not I'll just flag for a mod.

Comment: @Rachel I am never certain how to directly communication one on one with another SE user. I can leave an email address in a comment if you would like to discuss the other techniques I mentioned. Or if you know of some other communications channel, I am open to that.

Comment: How about [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39098/room-for-adam-zuckerman-and-rachel)?